# How do I translate a python generator function into ruby?

Tags: python, ruby, generator

I was wondering how to translate this bit of Python code into Ruby:

```
from __future__ import generators

def xcombinations(items, n):
    if n==0: yield []
    else:
        for i in xrange(len(items)):
            for cc in xcombinations(items[:i]+items[i+1:],n-1):
                yield [items[i]]+cc
```

--
my attempt at request:

```
def xcombinations(items, n)
    Fiber.new do
        if n == 0
            Fiber.yield []
        else
            for i in 0...items.length
                xcombinations(items[0...i]+items[i+1..-1],n-1).resume.each do |cc|
                    Fiber.yield [items[i]] << cc
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: put that in your question, comments are not the place for code

Comment: what is stack overflow then? I asked how to translate the code. I didn't ask you to translate it for me.

Comment: `items.combination(n)` results in a enumerator (a generator) in Ruby. (not sure I understand the python code)

Comment: "How do I translate a python generator function into ruby?" @jonrsharpe did you just say that because you dont know the answer to my question?

Comment: @user1376243 you said you didn't want the code translated for you (good, we don't do that) but that you wanted to know *how* to translate it. That's how.

Comment: @steenslag - i'm aware that I can use the ruby shortcut for this specefic example. I'm working with several python functions identical to this one in structure. So if I'm able to translate this one, I'll be able to translate the rest. Thanks for your reply though.

Comment: I don't think it's going to be productive if you're going to dismiss ruby built-ins. You appear to be looking for a way to make ruby code as pythonistic as possible. A translation should take advantage of the target language's idioms.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there is a general way to translate from python to ruby but at least your example, it can be translated by using Enumerator Class as follows.

```
def xcombinations(items, n)
    Enumerator.new do |y|
        if n == 0 then
            y << []
        else
            for i in 0...items.length
                xcombinations(items[0...i]+items[i+1..-1],n-1).each do |cc|
                    y << [items[i]]+cc
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```